# The authentication mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1" is not supported

Tags: mongodb

when i use mongoc_client_new to     user authentication， produce the error， 
The authentication mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1" is not supported.

what's the problem

Comment: are you also using the new server version?

Answer (score 0):

Your mongoc driver is trying to connect to a v3 mongo server while your mongoc driver was not linked with openSSL (with MONGOC_ENABLE_SSL).
see _mongoc_cluster_auth_node() function in mongoc-cluster.c

Answer (score 0):

First: Which language are you using? If it's c++, the error may be caused by the lack of initialization. A simple

```
  using mongo::client::initialize;
  Status status = initialize();
```

solved it for me.