# mongoc driver how to authenticate

Tags: mongodb, mongo-c-driver

I am having trouble with correct format of authenticating code. According to http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/authentication.html,
authenticate code is

```
mongoc_client_t *client = mongoc_client_new ("mongodb://user:password@localhost/?authSource=mydb");
```

And i have following code but it doesnt work:

```
client = mongoc_client_new ("mongodb://myuser:abcdefghjk@27.235.114.154/?authSource=books");
```

what should be the correct format to access db on server?

Comment: need details on the error presented both in the application itself and from the mongodb server log.

Comment: it simply returns nothing after i perform the query, I am assuming it's not connected to db on server

Comment: assertion 13 not authorized for query on books.bar2 ns:books.bar2 query:{ $query: {} }

Comment: 'The authentication mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1" is not supported.'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28448406/the-authentication-mechanism-scram-sha-1-is-not-supported